# Hide and Show function not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried hiding some drawer item in a drawer but it's can't do that.

code:

```
constructor(){
 super();
 this.state = {status: true}
 }
```

Sidebar:

```
 <TouchableOpacity   
   onPress={() => {
     if(this.state.status=true)
     {
       this.setState({status:false})
     }
     else
     {
       this.setState({status:true})
     }     
     }}>

    <Text>
      hide
    </Text>

  </TouchableOpacity>

  {this.state.status=true  ? <Text>drawer</Text>:null}
```

Refrence : https://reactnativecode.com/hide-show-view-component-button-onpress/

error:

[image]

Comment: `this.state.status=true` is an assignment. You want `this.state.status == true`, or just `this.state.status`. Could you include your entire component? There might be something else wrong that this code doesn't show since `this.state` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Tholle it's not working and error change...
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.status')
btw thx for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this one!

```
constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {status: true}
     }
```

Sidebar:

```
setStateByClick = () => {
    if(this.state.status)
         {
           this.setState({status:false})
         }
         else
         {
           this.setState({status:true})
         } 
    }

<TouchableOpacity  
   style={{ height:30, marginTop:10, marginLeft:70,}}  
   onPress={() => this.setStateByClick}>

    <Text style={{color: 'white',fontWeight:'bold',}} >
      hide
    </Text>

  </TouchableOpacity>

  {this.state.status  ? <Text>drawer</Text> : null }
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: First function defined and then call is not working for me so I directly call like this and it's not working

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(){
 super();
 this.state = {status: true}

 }
```

Note: please do not use `this.state.status === true` in your `if` condition just use this `this.state.status` for better and neat code

```
constructor(){
   super();
     this.state = {status: true}
   }



setSidebarState(){
    if(this.state.status)
         {
           this.setState({status:false})
         }
         else
         {
           this.setState({status:true})
         } 
    }

   <TouchableOpacity  
      style={{ height:30, marginTop:10, marginLeft:70,}}  
      onPress={() => this.setSidebarState()}>

       <Text style={{color: 'white',fontWeight:'bold',}} >
         hide
       </Text>

     </TouchableOpacity>

     {this.state.status  ? <Text>drawer</Text> : null }
```

Comment: it's not working same error.

Answer (score 1):

Use this it's more readable

```
render(){
  const { status } = this.state;
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={ () => this.setState({status:!status})}>
        <Text>Hey</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

     {status ? <Text>drawer</Text> : null}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: it's not working and error is: undefined status btw thx for the response